# I need assistance with a SQL sub-query

Tags: sql-server

This query:

```
SELECT j.job_name, c.command, c.job_ver, j.job_ver
FROM AEDB.dbo.ujo_command_job as c
INNER JOIN AEDB.dbo.ujo_job as j 
ON c.joid = j.joid
WHERE command LIKE '%$$XI1134%'
```

returns the following sample rows:

```
XI113TEST4-J    'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-6D-MMdDDdYYYY'      6   1
XI113TEST4-J    'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-6D-MMdDDdYYYY'      6   2
XI113TEST4-J    'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-6D-MMdDDdYYYY'      6   3
XI113TEST4-J    'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-6D-MMdDDdYYYY'      6   4
XI113TEST4-J    'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-6D-MMdDDdYYYY'      6   5
XI113TEST4-J    'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-6D-MMdDDdYYYY'      6   6
XI113TEST4-J    'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-6D-MMdDDdYYYY'      6   7
XI113TEST4-J-1  'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-6D-YYJJJ'           2   1
XI113TEST4-J-1  'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-6D-YYJJJ'           2   2
XI113TEST4-J-1  'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-6D-YYJJJ'           2   3
XI113TEST4-J-2  'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-7D-TO-MMdDDdYYYY'   2   1
XI113TEST4-J-2  'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-7D-TO-MMdDDdYYYY'   2   2
XI113TEST4-J-2  'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-7D-TO-MMdDDdYYYY'   2   3
XI113TEST4-J-3  'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-7D-TO-YYJJJ'        3   1
XI113TEST4-J-3  'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-7D-TO-YYJJJ'        3   2
XI113TEST4-J-3  'echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-7D-TO-YYJJJ'        3   3
```

How best can I modify the query so that the maximum value of j.job_ver (col 4) for any given jobname has to match c.job_ver (col 3).  Only the last row in the above sample should result.

The database keeps job versions, and I don't want info from older versions returning.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: And will your `c.command` column always start with `echo...` or can there be something else before `...$$XI1134...`?

Comment: Command can be anything. It will always include $$X1134, however.
SQL Server 2008, although the query will ultimately be executed in VBScript.

Comment: Gotcha. Then leave the wildcard in the WHERE.

Comment: Just a note. SQL Server 2008 is about to go EOL in a couple of months. After that, there will be no more security updates.

Comment: And both of my below answers should work in SQL2008. That one can do CTEs, but you'll still want to test with your actual data. The sub-query version will quite possibly be quicker.

Comment: One other suggestion I'd make would be to create a scheduled job that will archive older, unneeded rows to a different table. That will significantly cut down on the number of rows your `LIKE` will have to churn over.

Comment: Correction: I believe by the time your query gets to the `WHERE`, your `JOIN will have already filtered down to the max `j.job_ver` matches. But removing surplus rows should make that `JOIN` much faster.

Comment: Also, rather than a scheduled job to clean up, just do the archiving when you insert a new `j.job_ver` row. And only run a cleanup job the first time to get the old records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. Since you only want records with the max `ujo_job.job_ver`, then you can either calculate this record in a CTE or do it in a sub-query. Depending on your data, one may be more performant than the other. You'll have to test.

See my Fiddle for the setup I used (
*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=872e050a6f2b29dde0aa44f0c2bb7f56)*). If your data looks completely different, let me know and I'll take another stab at it.

**CTE VERSION:**

> ```
> ; WITH maxJobs AS (
>     SELECT j.joid, j.job_name, max(j.job_ver) as job_ver
>     FROM ujo_job j
>     GROUP BY j.joid, j.job_name
> )
> SELECT j2.job_name, c.command, c.job_ver, j2.job_ver
> FROM ujo_command_job c
> INNER JOIN maxJobs j2 ON c.joid = j2.joid
>     AND c.job_ver = j2.job_ver
> WHERE c.command LIKE '%$$XI1134%'
> ```
>
> ```
> job_name       | command                            | job_ver | job_ver
> :------------- | :--------------------------------- | ------: | ------:
> XI113TEST4-J-3 | echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-7D-TO-YYJJJ |       3 |       3
> ```

**SUB-QUERY VERSION:**

> ```
> SELECT s1.job_name, c.command, c.job_ver, s1.job_ver
> FROM ujo_command_job c
> INNER JOIN ( 
>     SELECT j.joid, j.job_name, max(j.job_ver) as job_ver
>     FROM ujo_job j
>     GROUP BY j.joid, j.job_name
> ) s1 ON c.joid = s1.joid
>     AND c.job_ver = s1.job_ver
> WHERE c.command LIKE '%$$XI1134%'
> ```
>
> ```
> job_name       | command                            | job_ver | job_ver
> :------------- | :--------------------------------- | ------: | ------:
> XI113TEST4-J-3 | echo $$XI1134*-NXT-BUS-7D-TO-YYJJJ |       3 |       3
> ```

<strike>I also changed your `WHERE` clause to do the `LIKE` after the first bit, rather than a wildcard at the start. If all of your `command`s start with `"echo..."`, then do this to make it process a good bit faster. If they can start with something else, leave the wildcard `%` in the query.</strike>

***EDIT:** Due to the new OP comments, they may have any text before the search string, so I've switched back to the wildcard search on both ends of the term. This will make for more processing, so if the leading text is constant, leave it without the leading wildcard.*

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you only need 'group by' with max():

```
SELECT j.job_name, c.command, c.job_ver, max(j.job_ver)
FROM AEDB.dbo.ujo_command_job as c
INNER JOIN AEDB.dbo.ujo_job as j 
ON c.joid = j.joid
WHERE command LIKE '%$$XI1134%'
group by j.job_name, c.command, c.job_ver
```

---

If this does not work for you, could you explain 'Only the last row in the above sample should result'?

Only the last row **for each category** will return?

Another question is: what does 'col4 has to match col3' mean?

col4 = col3  or col4 >= col3

---

**Update:**
Add one subquery to the above query:

```
SELECT a.job_name, a.command, a.job_ver, a.current_ver
from (
SELECT j.job_name, c.command, c.job_ver, max(j.job_ver) as current_ver
FROM AEDB.dbo.ujo_command_job as c
INNER JOIN AEDB.dbo.ujo_job as j 
ON c.joid = j.joid
WHERE command LIKE '%$$XI1134%'
group by j.job_name, c.command, c.job_ver )a
where a.job_ver = a.current_ver
```

Comment: You could alias `max(j.job_ver)` as `j_job_ver`, put this in a sub-query, and then after the subquery, use `WHERE job_ver = j_job_ver` to make both of those columns equal. I believe what OP means is that the last row in the example is the only one that meets the desired conditions.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=88c3b7ff6ea086bfe2453cd92f253848

Comment: Out of the sample rows I posted, only the very last one should be a valid match, since the job is version 3.  The first job (XI113TEST4-J) for example, should return no valid matches since its currently at version 7 (col4) but there col3 only shows version 6

Comment: This also works...I wish i could 'accept' multiple solutions.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you only need to put that condition within your JOIN `c.job_ver = j.job_ver`

So, your query would like this :

```
SELECT 
    j.job_name
,   c.command
,   c.job_ver
,   j.job_ver
FROM 
    AEDB.dbo.ujo_command_job as c
INNER JOIN AEDB.dbo.ujo_job as j 
ON c.joid = j.joid AND c.job_ver = j.job_ver
WHERE 
    command LIKE '%$$XI1134%'
```

Comment: This doesnt work, as rows 6, 9, and 12 also return, giving us old job version info

Comment: @EphronClarke do you have any datetime column inside ujo_command_job or ujo_job ? if yes then put it in the sample you have. Also, could you show `joid` with the sample, this would give us a better view.